# Connecting to MS Access

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access

I am trying to connect my small C# program which has only one Insert Query with MS Access database. I followed up some codes in Internet but i couldn't get it right.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\HP\Desktop\victoriy\Database1.accdb);

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        con.Open();
        cmd.CommandText = "Insert into Na(FirstName,LastName)Values('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "')";
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Record Submitted", "Congrats");
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What exactly is the problem with this code? Please specify any errors, what you did expect, what did happen

Comment: You appear to be missing a `"` from the end of your connection string. I'd also recommend looking at [parameterising your query](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Query_Parameterization_Cheat_Sheet) to avoid the risk of SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Oh, and please research the phrase "SQL injection"

Comment: When i click the Add button, it doesnt say anything also nothing get inserted in my database

Comment: Even after i put " at end of the connection String, it is not working at all.....Nothing happening.....

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint in your `button1_Click` method and stepped through the code?

Comment: It's Solved by adding slash marks in other way round